# Why can I not finish sign up?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-exchange-openid, sign-up

I always have this thing at the top of the screen next to my name that says "finish signup". [image: Finish Signup]

So, I click on it, and see what happens. I get to this screen, and I enter a password.

[image: Entering Password]

After I do that, it rederects me back to the electrical engineering home and it still says "finish signup". What is wrong with this, and Why can't I sign up, I think I have enough reputation. I wish to be able to vote, so this is why I want to finish signup.

UPDATE:
 I have tried it on many browsers, firefox, safari, chrome, flock, torbrowser, internet explorer. I have tried it on a mac, a pc, and even linux, I have tried it on many library computers at school, no luck

Comment: You might find some of the troubleshooting steps [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176275/infinite-loop-finish-signing-up-by-setting-a-password-for-your-account?rq=1) useful.

Comment: I don't have NoScript, I have tried it on many browsers, firefox, safari, chrome, flock, torbrowser, internet explorer. I have tried it on a mac, a pc, and even linux, I have tried it on many library computers at school, no luck

Comment: Wait, flock? Where did you get flock? :D

Comment: So everything but **Opera**

Comment: http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/19719/flock is where i got flock

Comment: @Skyler440 are you still having this issue?  If so, can you collect any information using browser dev tools to see if there's a Javascript problem somewhere?  I haven't yet been able to reproduce this behavior.

Comment: no it works now